# Code based Servlet Initializer doesn't behave the same as web.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am having a strange issue with converting my spring xml based servlet config to a code/annotation based initialisation using AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

**Edited:**
The code builds fine but the request mapping doesn't work correctly.  In the code based config it will only handle requests if i put the request mapping to "/`*" and not "/", however as i want to serve up JSP pages with a view resolver I cant use "/`*" as it stops that from functioning correctly.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Spring version is 3.2.4

XML based servlet intialization

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>my.package.SpringConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>dispatchOptionsRequest</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Code based servlet intialization

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { SpringConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

@Override
public void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
    registration.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true");
    registration.setInitParameter("dispatchOptionsRequest", "true");
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
}
```

}

Comment: _if i put the request mapping to "/" and not "/"_  -  I think there is a mistake in your mappings, right?

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise i needed to escape * characters on SO, have corrected above.  Works when i use /* but not when i use /  In web.xml / works fine, jsut not in the code.